# Creating a "merge module" for a web project

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, asp.net-2.0, web-setup-project

My group uses merge modules on various projects which is then added to a setup project.  This simplifies deployment by having only one .msi for our entire suite of functionality and allows us to have one entry under Add/Remove Programs.  I cannot find a way to do this with a web setup project given there is no "Web Setup Merge Module" project type.  If I simply add project output from a website, no aspx files are deployed (only the assemblies), if I create a Web Setup project, then only the resultant .msi is deployed...it is not installed.

So, the question is: Is there a recommended way to deploy a web project as part of a larger installation (ala merge module) so there is one entry in Add/Remove Programs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setup projects available in Visual Studio only cover a tiny subset of the functionality of Windows Installer. Have a look at [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) from Microsoft. It exposes pretty much all Windows Installer functionality without having to buy expensive commercial products. It integrates into Visual Studio, so you can create a "WiX setup project" as easily as a built-in one.

Comment: WIX indeed looks powerful, but doesn't look nearly as easy to use, nor do I like the fact that (it seems) I'd have to add all files I want installed to the WIX files, which could be a maintenance nightmare.